# How to remove root from json source in data flow (Azure Data Factory)?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm having troubles performing a join on two of my sources. The problem is that in one of my sources there is a json root object, and in the other there is not. Like the following:

Source A:

```
{
  'movies': [
    {
      'title': 'movieA',
      'released': 2019
    },
    {
      'title': 'movieB',
      'released': 2015
    }
  ]
}
```

Source B:

```
[
  {
    'title': 'movieA',
    'released': 2019
  },
  {
    'title': 'movieC',
    'released': 2014
  }
]
```

I'm expecting the result to look like:

```
[
  {
    'title': 'movieA',
    'released': 2019
  },
  {
    'title': 'movieB',
    'released': 2015
  },
  {
    'title': 'movieC',
    'released': 2014
  }
]
```

This is making it possible for me to not make a data flow, as Source B will 2 columns (title and released), but Source A will only have one column (movies). How do I fix this such that Source A will only have the two columns (title and released) so I can perform joins/unions/selects and such?

I should mention that I get the data from two APIs, and I use pipelines in ADF to copy from the API to a local storage account just using a copy activity. So if there is a solution that I can implement in my copy activity pipeline then I'm also happy to hear it.

Comment: Can you show what is the expected data look like?

Comment: @LeonYue I haved updated the post with the expected result.

Comment: @Cralle did you find a solution? I' facing the same issue.